# Min-width and Max-width css media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
<link href="css/mobile-large.css" media="all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 760px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Shouldn't that line of code do so that the stylesheet "mobile-large.css" be loaded when using a Samsung Galaxy Nexus with 720px in width? However it doesn't so what is the reason and how do I fix it?

I am using this too:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you have to define `device-width` instead of simple width. Write like this:

```
<link href="css/mobile-large.css" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 760px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: That works, but why? When the browswer window is equal to the size of the screen shouldn't device-width and width work equally? See my updated question where I state that I use the meta tag viewport

Comment: And why does iPhone 4 and iPhone 3G have the same dimensions? They get the same CSS, but the iPhone 4 have doubled the pixels?

Answer (score 1):

I think also you can remove "all and" from the query string.