# Different set of background Images for different resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a full screen background image slideshow with 29 images. The images shows perfect on (1366 x 769)px resolution, but when I use a different resolution which is lower than this, most of the part of the image is not shown. And when the resolution is too big, the background color(white) appears at right and bottom.

The way I figured out to check screen resolution with javascript is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ((screen.width=1400) && (screen.height<=900)) {

}
if ((screen.width=1366) && (screen.height<=768)) {

}
else {

}
</script>
```

Now, how should I use the images below in the code above?

```
<img src="1400/images/background/bg-2.jpg"> 
<img src="1400/images/background/bg-3.jpg"/>
...
<img src="1400/images/background/bg-29.jpg"/>
```

and

```
<img src="1366/images/background/bg-2.jpg"> 
<img src="1366/images/background/bg-3.jpg"/>
...
<img src="1366/images/background/bg-29.jpg"/>
```

I cannot use CSS for this as the images are displayed with html code.

Answer (score 1):

Set your background with CSS and than try out Media-Queries

http://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries

Something like:

```
@media (width: 800px) {
    body {
        background-image: url('image1.jpg');
    }
}

@media (width: 1200px) {
    body {
        background-image: url('image2.jpg');
    }
}
```

or do it with different files

[Min-width and Max-width css media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513931/min-width-and-max-width-css-media-queries)

or write your own script to the end. Maybe by using jQuery and appending css-files if you need them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var $background = jQuery('<img class="background" src="fallback.jpg" alt="" />');

        if (jQuery(window).width() == 1400 && jQuery(window).height() <= 900) {
            // jQuery('head').prepend('<link href="styles1.css" ... />');
            // or
            $background.attr('src', 'image2.jpg');
        }

        [...]

        $background.appendTo('body');
    });    
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    img.background {
        /* style your background e.g. */
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        border: 0 none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I cannot use CSS for this as the images have a combined size of over 5mb. If I do use CSS, it will load all images, I don't want to do that. I want it to load only specific set of images for that resolution.

Comment: algorhythem, CSS media queries wouldn't solve the issue that all those assets would be loaded in, even if they're not being used. This is an unfortunate problem with media queries that affects all the major browsers.

Comment: @AshleySheridan ok, that is new to me and it sucks :-(

Answer (score 1):

To avoid loading the wrong images, I would add those image tags in with Javascript right from the start. Then, you just add them with the corresponding path that you determine in your first Javascript snippet.

One thing I would say is that you shouldn't attempt to match the width exactly. Match in the same way as you are for the height of the screen. The reason I say this is because a visitor may not have their window maximised, and the resolution might not be what you expect (as an example my webstats for the year show a mix of over 100 completely different screen resolutions).

Also, you should probably not use the .width property but the availWidth. That will prevent one problem where users don't have their browser windows maximised and one where they might have a sidebar (bookmarks, etc) open which would eat into the display area.

If the images are already on the page and you can't change that, you could change their SRC properties with Javascript. This would mean that two sets of images were loaded at most though. As you haven't provided more HTML around that example, I can't say what the code would be to select those specifically. Do they all exist within a div that has a certain ID, or do they all share a class attribute that you didn't put in your example?

Comment: is there any way to change the html text in the javascript.

Comment: jQuery('.dom-element').text('text here');

Comment: and any way to change the the source of div images?

Answer (score 0):

Go for a jQuery plugin. Supersized is one of my fave.

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Comment: I was already using it, but the preloader fails when images are over 5, in my case I am using 29. So I kind of switched :)